# Установить значение из выпадающего списка как выбранное

Tags: javascript

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_option_label3

Через кнопку меняется текст в выпадающем списке на другой: пункт изменился на `new label` и этот изменившийся элемент установился вместо `"Volvo"`.

Как сделать, чтобы при изменении значения `label 1,2,3...` менялся и устанавливался пункт из `drop down list`?

То есть: в `label == 0` и в `ddl` нет изменений, если `label == 1`, то этот `"1"` имеет совпадение `<option value="1" id="value1_1">этот пункт</option>`
и тд...

Total Selected : 0

вот тут функция прописана в применении, которая, соответствующий пункт из выпадающего списка делает на виду,

```
function GetSelectedText()
{
    var first_1 = document.getElementById("total").textContent;

var second_2 = document.getElementById('LimitedCheckboxes1').value; //value from ddl

if(first_1 === "0")
    {
        alert(second_2);
        document.getElementById("0").text="0й Пункт будет выбран (вместо юзера)";
    }
    if(first_1 === "1")
    {
        alert(second_2);
        document.getElementById("1").text="1й Пункт будет выбран (вместо юзера)";
    }
```

Comment: добавьте воспроизводимый пример, так тяжело понять что вам нужно

Comment: @meine добавил..